# spring boot client app interaction with pcf config server backed by hashicorp vault?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, hashicorp-vault, pcf

I am working on spring boot app which will be deployed in pcf and it will use pcf config server service which is backed by hashicorp vault. What I would like to know is which dependencies I should be adding in my spring boot app other that spring-cloud-config-client. Do I need to add spring-cloud-vault, if yes then why does it need to be added if app only talks to config server? I would like to know how this end to end interaction works.

Comment: It only needs to be added to config server

Comment: I am using PCF provided config server, so how can I add it in there?

Comment: https://docs.run.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-services/config-server/configuring-with-vault.html